# Как убрать вылеты из Android 7?

Tags: android, webview

Ошибка:

> Android App has stopped. Open app again.

Использую код:

***Android Manifest:***

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <activity android:name="riddle.russia.MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

***MainActivity:***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String url ="file:///android_asset/index.html";
        WebView view= (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);

        view.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);


        view.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        view.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        view.setInitialScale(1);
    }
}
```

***activity_main:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="riddle.russia.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Стектрейс при вылете нужно прикладывать, если вам нужны полезные ответы.

Comment: @pavlofff, что-то мне подсказывает, что у него в `AppTheme` скрыто `Holo.Light.Что.То.Там`.

Comment: Что такое [стектрэйс и где он](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/stacktraces.html)